# Continuous/repeating WKInterfacePicker for Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I'm wondering if anyone has figured out how to make the `WKInterfacePicker` repeat after the last item, so that it forms a continuous loop? I know this is possible with `UIPickerView` in `UIKit`, but like most `WatchKit` objects `WKInterfacePicker` has very limited accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

One work-around I figured is to have a long list of WKPickerItem of repeating items. You want it REALLY LONG, so that it wears the patience of even the naughtiest users who try to catch you cheating.

You can always determine the desired index by simple modulo operation.

Well, I'm also looking for a better answer to reveal the official way of doing this...

Comment: This is exactly what I did to solve the problem. I also used a stack of 3 interface groups that collapse into each other depending on the direction you scroll, so that only one group is showing at all times. This gives the illusion that whatever's in the group is on a dial.